# Pin Arrangement which one should i follow?

Tags: pins, decoder

I have 2 different arrangement of 7448 IC's pins, and I'm not sure which one I should follow. The two different pin arrangements I found for the IC are:

- [www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/247381/RENESAS/HD74LS48P.html](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/247381/RENESAS/HD74LS48P.html)
- [www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/27434/TI/SN74LS48N.html](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/27434/TI/SN74LS48N.html)

The circuit I'm trying to make is making is diagrammed [here](http://vbvyas.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/hoursminutesseconds.png). According to this circuit diagram it should be connected in different way.  I have two questions:

- Should I use the datasheet I found on alldatasheet or the one I have?
- Can I  mix HD74lS48p and SN74lS48n?

Comment: Can you post the full link (even if not `A HREF`) to the second datasheet? Cutting and pasting URLs makes me unhappy. Also we don't know which datasheet "you have" and which datasheet you found on alldatasheet. The wordpress link contains no datasheets: it is a _circuit diagram_.

Comment: okay done :) i dont have datasheet only this graph. but i was told by friend that i should follow the graph so G,F,E,D,C,B,A instead of f,g,a,b,c,d,e he wasn't confidence  tho

Comment: What looks different to you between the two pin arrangements? Just so you know, the image in the wordpress link is called a _circuit diagram_: calling it a _graph_ is confusing.

Comment: everything thats why i'm not sure .. sry my English isn't perfect

Comment: OK, let's see... On HD74lS48p pin 1 is Input B, pin 2 is input C and pin 3 is Lamp test. On SN74LS48N, pin 1 is labeled "B", pin 2 "C" and pin 3 is "LT". Can you be specific about the differences you see?

Comment: they are the same but sorted in different way

Comment: the difference i see is in the segment output order ah  are you trying to say that they are the same and in the diagram they shuffle the order of output and i am too stupid to notice this  .. ty.

Comment: I don't see any difference. Pin 15 is F, pin 14 is G, etc.  Can you be _very specific_ about a difference you see for a _particular pin_?

Comment: i didnt noticed that the pin numbers didnt changed what i noticed at first that the order of letters are shuffled

Comment: btw am not engineering student. so i didnt study this in details... hmm feel free to post an answer to close this topic. again ty for letting me see this :)

Comment: @angelatlarge it sounds like you answered this, maybe post an answer? Explain everything you had to explain in comments so there is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the two pinouts side by side, it becomes easier to compare the pins.  In the following image the Renesas chip (HD74LS48P) is on the left, and the TI chip (the SN74LS48N) is on the right.

[image]

Going down from pin 1 to pin 8 we have for the two chips

- HD74LS48P: `Input B` / SN74LS48N: `B`
- HD74LS48P: `Input C` / SN74LS48N: `C`
- HD74LS48P: `Lamp Test` / SN74LS48N: `LR`
- HD74LS48P: `BI/RBO` / SN74LS48N: `RBO`
- HD74LS48P: `RBI` / SN74LS48N: `RBI`
- HD74LS48P: `Input D` / SN74LS48N `D`
- HD74LS48P: `Input A` / SN74LS48N `A`
- HD74LS48P: `GND` / SN74LS48N `GND`

Similar correspondence obtains on the right. Therefore we conclude that the pinouts are identical.

Note that the HD74LS48P chip is not recommended for new designs.

Comment: btw i didn't mean to compare between HD74LS48P and SN74LS48N i meant between these two(which are identical) and the one in the circuit diagram

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the second link, which is: (http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/27434/TI/SN74LS48N.html).

The first link leads to a datasheet which has the words "Not recommended for new design" across it.

Also, notice that the second one is SN74LS48N. That means that it is a low-schottky 7448 made by Texas Instruments in a PDIP package. If you are using a plastic DIP IC, you should follow the second one.

Oh, and can't you just use a 7442?

Comment: Mmm.. I think this answer is a bit misleading: the OP was asking about the pinout, which is identical, as far as I can tell.

Comment: yea angel is correct at first i didnt notice that they are the same because of the location of the pin number were shuffled in the diagram . this is the first time dealing with circuits